# Blacklist [stackoverflow] meta tag?

Tags: support, meta, blocklist-request

Since this is a "real" meta site now, it would seem that tagging questions with [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) is redundant.

Shouldn't it be blacklisted to prevent its use?

Especially since a large percentage of the questions being "tossed over the fence" from Meta Stack Exchange will be tagged as such.

Comment: Not to be confused with [stack-overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stack-overflow/info) which is about stack overflows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see a need to blacklist the tag, no. I'm sure we can keep up for now cleaning up the tag here.

Only if it is being *persistently* recreated after the migration dust has settled, would the tag need blacklisting. But I don't think it'll ever be abused like that.

Note that blacklisting can only be done by a Stack Exchange developer and is reserved for persistently re-created tags only.

Comment: If I remember right it was posted that blacklisting is something that should be done as a last resort because of the resources that enforcing the blacklist takes

Comment: @JoeW: correct, it takes a developer to create one.

Comment: While that is true in general, intrinsic tags are usually blacklisted from the start. Intrinsic tags are e.g. [tag:ubuntu] on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @MadScientist: `ubuntu` on Ask Ubuntu is a synonym for `ubuntu-desktop`. Did you mean `ubuntu` on Meta Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: Looks like I should check my examples. But in general, the site topic or name is often blacklisted immediately.

Comment: @MadScientist: `stackoverflow` on Stack Overflow is not blacklisted either. :-) Anywho, this is my opinion, I don't see a need just yet.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'd hope `stackoverflow` isn't blacklisted, it's a viable question category (not directly related to the site itself) :P

Comment: @ty1824: I tend to forget that! Python doesn't suffer from stack overflows (much), and thus the site name is the first thing that springs to mind...

Comment: @ty1824: I was referring to the tag here on Meta Stack Overflow to refer to the main site, not the tag on Stack Overflow itself which refers to, well, stack overflows.